# Dart/Flutter support for delegates

Tags: delegates, dart, flutter

Does Dart 2.0 support the concept of a delegate? Having reviewed the documentation I assume not. So is this is an omission? Or is there an alternate approach to achieving the same? Possibly using streams?

Comment: What kind of delegation are you looking for?

Comment: A page calls a route which calls another route. Tthen an action pops both the second route and calls a delegate to Also pop the first route.

Comment: This is unrelated to Dart. You're looking for a Flutter feature?

Comment: No, looking for a language feature (dart) to use with the framework (flutter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only one that I know of that is delegate "like" is `typedef`. It really is a way to strongly type callbacks. A common one is [`WidgetBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetBuilder.html)

```
typedef Widget WidgetBuilder(BuildContext context);
```

or the more preferred way of writing a callback

```
typedef WidgetBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context);
```

But you can also build your own